# Shorten the number of logical checks

Tags: python, logic

Is there a way to shorten the number of checks

```
    def is_render(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'p') : return True
        if hasattr(self, 'p') and 'render' not in self.p : return True
        if hasattr(self, 'p') and 'render' in self.p and self.p['render'] != 0 : return True
        return False
```

i.e.

```
if not A : true
elif A and not B : true
elif A and B and not C : true
else false
```

... even better if I can check simultaneously  `x != 0 or x is not False`

Comment: What's up with the repeat checks? Can their values change in between?

Comment: in a sense the default is True to render .. and false only when explicitly set to > 1 or true ....hmm tats two checks only !

Comment: I mean why do you check `hasattr(self, 'p')` up to three times? Once is enough.

Comment: u are correct i can store it in a var

Comment: Huh? No, just don't check it again.

Comment: ooo u meant using if-else

Comment: Once you have passed `if not hasattr`, then you KNOW it has the attribute, and you don't need to check it again.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if not A : true
elif A and not B : true
elif A and B and not C : true
else false
```

is equivalent to:

```
if A:
    if B:
        if C:
            return False
return True
```

As demonstrated by the following test...

```
from itertools import product

def check_1(A, B, C):
    if not A:
        return True
    elif A and not B:
        return True
    elif A and B and not C:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def check_2(A, B, C):
    if A:
        if B:
            if C:
                return False
    return True

for each in product([True, False], repeat=3):
    if check_1(*each) == check_2(*each):
        result = "equivalent"
    else:
        result = "not equivalent"

    print(f"{each}\t-> {result}")
```

...which returns:

```
(True, True, True)      -> equivalent
(True, True, False)     -> equivalent
(True, False, True)     -> equivalent
(True, False, False)    -> equivalent
(False, True, True)     -> equivalent
(False, True, False)    -> equivalent
(False, False, True)    -> equivalent
(False, False, False)   -> equivalent
```

Of course it'd be possible to us an `all` expression like this...

```
def check_3(A, B, C):
    return False if all([A, B, C]) else True
```

...and get the exact same result (I've checked). But I'm guessing you want to only check certain conditions if other conditions have already evaluated as True, for fear of an exception or something - hence the nested ifs.

Not sure if this meets your definition of "shorter", or whether it addresses your original issue - but hope this helps anyhow.

Comment: Can't you do something like ````def is_render(self):
    return ('render' not in self.p or (self.p['render'] != 0 or self.p['render'] is not False)) if hasattr(self, 'p') else False
```` to make it shorter

Comment: Yes, shouldn't always check B and C. I'd do `return not (A and B and C)`.

Comment: `return not hasattr(self, 'p') or not 'render' in self.p or self.p['render'] != 0`?

Comment: `C` wouldn't get evaluated there.

Comment: I suspect you did something wrong there, `C` doesn't get evaluated there.

Answer (score 1):

this seem to do it too.. default is True, only explicitly rendering can be turned off

```
def is_render(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'p') and 'render' in self.p and self.p['render'] == 0 : return False
    return True
```

thanks for the suggestions